# Quick Question: Why do VC++ compiled exe's stop working if I change their names?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working on a command prompt roguelike in VisualC++ 2008, and everything compiles all fine and dandy, but there's one glaring issue that I have with it.

Why is it that if I change the name of the exe, the program fails completely?  I don't think that's supposed to happen with most programs

Comment: What does fail completely mean? Completely ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely because of the manifest file - you'll either need to rename the manifest file as well or embed it into the exe, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944276

Comment: Ah, thank you, I understand that, and that much IS resolved.  However, I do have one additional problem here.  I'm trying to distribute the EXE to some friends, but they get "side by side" configuration" errors or "app config is incorrect."

I want to compile it in /MT, but it gives me all kinds of crazy linker errors, and I don't want to use /MTd because it makes the file size huge.

Comment: 1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg referenced in function "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg referenced in function "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int)"
1>4chRogue.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Comment: you are trying to link the non-debug c runtime with your program which was compiled for the debug c runtime. are you compiling /MT and defining _DEBUG?

Comment: You have runtime library conflicts... see this MSDN article for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Also, if you are sending your friends a debug .exe, and they don't have Visual Studio installed, then you need to also send them the debug runtime .dlls.

Comment: IANAL, but I think it is against the VS EULA to distribute debug runtime DLLs.

If you have any more "Application configuration" issues, you probably need them to have the appropriate VC runtime redistributable file. It's part of your VS installation or available on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't happen unless the program itself is designed to check its own exe's name and behave differently accordingly. You need to post some code.

Comment: I never specified anything like this within my code, I believe it has something to do with the project options but I don't know what it is.  When I change the name I get this error:

This application has failed to start because MSVCR90D.dll was not found.